# Android Cursor Issue with Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, cursor

I'm trying to make an app that tells me whats the next meeting in my calendar.
What I did is place a cursor on the last event and start getting their start times until I get to the one that's smaller than right now, then, simply use the previous item.
It works fine when creating events in order but not if I create an event in between.
Here is an example:

Lets set the time to 13:00 hours
I have events that I added before at 15:00 (event 1), 16:00 (event 2), 17:00 (event 3)
The cursor goes to read the start time of event 3.
Since the start time is bigger than right now, it goes to previous one, event 2
since start time is also bigger, it goes to previous one, event 1.
Since start time is also bigger, it goes to previous one, some event yesterday.
Since start is smaller, it gets the id, title and start and end times from event 1.

That all works fine, the problem is, when I add something at lets say 14:00 (event 0) after initially added the others first, events 1, 2 and 3
It wont get to event 0, it keeps the information of event 1.

How can I make so that it is correctly made?

here is my code

Big thanks in advance

Regards

```
public class CalendarInfo extends Activity {
int idNumber = 0;
private Cursor mCursor = null;
private static final String[] COLS = new String[]
{ CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,      CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events._ID};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_info);
Button buttonchange999 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button999);
        buttonchange999.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, null);
            mCursor.moveToLast();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            long currentTimeStart = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            long ammountOfDayPassed = currentTimeStart/86400000;
            String title = "N/A";
            Long start = 9223372036854775806L;
            Long end = 0L;
            int id = 0;
            String title2 = "N/A";
            Long start2 = 9223372036854775806L;
            Long end2 = 0L;
            int id2 = 0;
            while(start>currentTimeStart){
            try {
            title = mCursor.getString(0);
            start = mCursor.getLong(1);
            end = mCursor.getLong(2);
            id = mCursor.getInt(3);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore
            }
            if(start>currentTimeStart){
                title2 = title;
                start2 = start;
                end2 = end;
                id2 = id;
            }
            mCursor.moveToPrevious();
            }

            DateFormat formatter01 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Calendar calendar01 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar01.setTimeInMillis(start2);
            String startText = formatter01.format(calendar01.getTime());
            DateFormat formatter02 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Calendar calendar02 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar02.setTimeInMillis(end2);
            String endText = formatter02.format(calendar02.getTime());

            if(start2>currentTimeStart && end2>currentTimeStart){
            settingsTextView.setText("Meeting: "+title2+"\n"+"At: "+startText+"\n"+"Until: "+endText+"\n"+"ID: "+id2);
            idNumber=id2;
            }
            else{
                settingsTextView.setText("No Next Meeting" + "\n" + "Meeting: "+title2+"\n"+"At: "+startText+"\n"+"Until: "+endText+"\n"+"ID: "+id2);
                idNumber=id2;
        }
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding one if in this line:

```
if(start>currentTimeStart){
if(start<start2){
            title2 = title;
            start2 = start;
            end2 = end;
            id2 = id;
        }
}
```